# What's so special about optional typing in dart

Tags: dart, duck-typing

What's so special about "optional typing"?

People are very enthusiastic about Dart supporting "optional typing", but once a language supports duck typing - can't I take optional typing for granted? Isn't it an obvious feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify types annotations you're passing information to both fellow developers and tools.

Consider this (fairly long) example of two functions - the first with no type info, the second with type info:

```dart
createConnection(details) {
  var foo = details.host; // assume details has a host property
  // do stuff
  return connection;
}
```

versus

```dart
Connection createConnection(ConnectionParams details) {
  var foo = details.host; // tools can validate that details has a host property
  // do stuff
  return connection;
}
```

When you call the first function, you need to know (from either reading API docs, or the sourcecode) that the function takes something which has a `host` field.  You also need to know that the function returns a `Connection` object, not a string or something else.

When you call the second function, you know that you can pass in any object that meets the interface defined by `ConnectionParams`, and you know that a `Connection` object is returned.

Let's say you have two classes:

```dart
class MySqlConn {
  String host;
}

class PostgreSqlConn {
  String host;
}


// elsewhere
var conn = new MySqlConn()..host = '127.0.0.1';
createConnection(conn);
```

Although though it's valid duck typing, there is no connection in code between the first function and these classes, other than they both have a field with the same name: `host`.

Looking at these two classes, I can't tell that one use of them is to pass an instance of them into the `createConnection()` function (and it's very hard for tools to understand that, too). I can't create API docs for the `createConnection` function that link back to these two classes.

When you add a little more type information, **communicating intent**, suddenly everything comes together.

```dart
// define an interface
abstract class ConnectionParams { 
  String host;
}

// inform tools and humans that MySqlConn implements the interface
class MySqlConn implements ConnectionParams {
  String host;
}

class PostgreSqlConn implements ConnectionParams {
  String host;
}
```

Now both tools and humans can form links in static code from the second `createConnection` function back to the classes and ultimately the interface.  With the first example, the link is only made at runtime.

Comment: I'll try to sum it up: If I understood correctly, you're saying that you could write a function that doesn't specify types, but in order for the function's purpose to be clear to other programmers, you _do_ want to specify its inputs and output types - and Dart allows that (returning a type even though it's specified as a "var"). Did I understand correctly? Still, I can't really see the difference between that and duck typing... (sorry). Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly. The guideline from the [style guide](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/style-guide/) is **PREFER providing type annotations on public APIs** - that is, where other developers interface with your code, type annotations are very helpful.  With duck typing although the code works, there's no documentary link between parts of the code until the code actually executes.